# Калькулятор javascript которы из строки с выражением вычисляет результат

Tags: javascript

Есть необходимость написать калькулятор который мог бы из поля `input` брать выражение вида

```
'12/5*9+9.4*2'
```

и вычислять результат.

Насколько верно использовать такой вариант:

```js
var calc = function(fn) 
{
  return new Function('return ' + fn)();
}

console.log(calc('12/5*9+9.4*2'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде, это тот же [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) => все + и - его.

```js
    let calc = (fn) => new Function('return ' + fn)();
    
    console.log(calc('alert("test")'));
```

Comment: не совсем тот же.

Comment: да, вообще это не eval, но в данном случае он работает именно так и эту конструкцию можно заменить на eval(fn). если ошибаюсь, то скажите где) почитаем, учтем)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого имеется функция `eval`・

```js
alert(eval("10+10*10"));
```